# How to know the default connection or last used connection

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I need to find out what the last connection (connection OLEDBConnection) used in a workbook or the connection name that is active in a `PivotTable` in `VBA - Excel`

Comment: What did you try already ?

Comment: I can have the number of connections and their names, but I do not know what the last used or which is active.

Sub nCon()
    Dim n As Single
    For n = ActiveWorkbook.Connections.Count To 1 Step -1
        Debug.Print ActiveWorkbook.Connections(n)
    Next n
End Sub

Answer (score 0):

Consegui. segue código:

`Sub DescobrirCon()`

`Dim pvt As PivotTable`

```
For Each pvt In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).PivotTables 

       Debug.Print pvt.PivotCache.WorkbookConnection 

Next pvt
```

`End Sub`

Comment: please try to write your answer in English so that others can understand